How does Akabeko's strengh buff work with Double Tap?
In Slay the Spire: The Board Game, the Akabeko relic says:

Once per combat: Gain Strength for one Attack.

The Double Tap card says:

This turn, your next Attack is played twice.

If I use Akabeko to buff my strength then play Double Tap so my next attack is played twice, does my strength get buffed for both times that attack card gets played?
